# Adding custom CSS to Drupal 7 to hide the message

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

I use my custom block for displaying a flash game at the front page of [my Drupal 7 installation](http://h1770839.stratoserver.net/), but there is also the annoying message:

```
<div id="first-time"><p>No front page content has been created yet.</p>
<div class="item-list"><ul><li class="first last">
<a href="/node/add">Add new content</a></li> 
</ul></div></div>
```

below it and I can't remove it. Is there please a hook for adding custom CSS? In my module I would like to make the **#first-time** light grey or invisible.

I prefer not to add a blank content just to get rid of that text.

Thank you!
Alex

**UPDATE:**

I've added the following to my module:

```
function game_init() {
  drupal_set_message('XXX init called XXX');
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    drupal_add_css('#first-time {color: green;}', 'inline');
  }
}
```

but don't see that CSS-code or XXX string inside my front page.

**UPDATE2**:

Oh, I had to clear the cache and now it works (the Drupal docs seem to be wrong here - there was written that 'inline' CSS is not cached...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiding the CSS is the WRONG way of doing it. why did you created your content as a **Custom Block**?

- you should create a "**Page**" and set this page as **front page** in the Configuration->Site Information.

Whatever. you can also use any of these options but is **not recommended**.

- you can also also add a BlankPage by Adding only the Title(then hiding it in PHP on page.tpl.php)
- you can add your css in /templates/themes/bartik.info
- you can call drupal_add_css on the _init() hook of your custom module.

Blocks are used to display information in every page(although we can set to display only on certain pages). Say For Example. A Menu, or A Shopping Cart etc.

Comment: Ok, that is a good point. What hook should I overwrite to create a page (a node?) which would embed my flash game? Please write few lines of code for a Hello-World page, if possible

Comment: @Alexander Farber: why would you need to write a hook to embed your flash game?? if you set your "Text Format" in body to "Full html". you can embedd any html tags in a page(the so called node).

Comment: No, I need the hook because I pass user id, avatar, gender and city through the FlashVars parameter to the .swf file of my game. So I have written a game_block_view() to do that. But a node is probably better here?

Comment: @Alexander Farber: if you are a coder-kind-of guy you can add drupal_add_css() in game_init() function of your custom module "game". and if your a admin-kind-of you can enable "PHP Filter" module which will bring a new "Text Format" for the content.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some CSS for a module, you should use [drupal_add_css()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css)

Comment: So I have to call drupal_add_css('#first-time { color: white; }', 'inline'); but from where? From my game_block_view(); ?

Comment: A nice way to add CSS is to implement a [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) in your module and put the drupal_add_inside() inside.

Comment: For some reason my game_init() is not called, but game_block_view(),  game_block_info() and game_user_login() are called ok. Do I need to clear cache or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add this CSS to your theme?

Comment: Thanks, but where? Can't find it in Administration menu for Bartik theme

Comment: @AlexanderFarber You'll have to edit the css files in the theme directly - you'll fidn them wherever you put your theme (ie. in the /themes/ directory, or /sites/all/themes/ )